# Applet in web page - Know how to transfer contents to new (J)Frame but how to vice versa? (Whilst running)

Tags: java, web, applet, jframe, fullscreen

Okay people, I'm not really a programmer but I do know most of the basics of Java and some advanced techniques.

But I am totally lost on my web application where I want to turn the game to fullscreen then return back to normal.

What I do know is I need to create a new JFrame and place the contents of the applet to the JFrame by using frame.add(applet).

The problem is when I have fullscreened my JFrame and want to return back to normal screen, I have no idea how to transfer the contents of my JFrame back to the web applet, when I try do applet.add(frame.getContentPane()) I get error saying I can't add the parent of it there, EVEN after I have disposed the JFrame

EDIT: I got it to switch the content back, I guess.. but the applet stays white even I did reference the applet Graphics graphic = applet.getGraphics() after the transform of jframe to applet.. weird!

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(applet.getContentPane()); //applet == JApplet
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setResizable(false);
device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
```

That code I use to turn the content from applet over the fullscreened jframe, now I want to dismiss fullscreen and return contents of jframe back to the applet, I get error saying I can't add parent something back to it.

```
if (device.getFullScreenWindow() != null) {
     device.getFullScreenWindow().dispose();
     device.setFullScreenWindow(null); 
     applet.setContentPane(frame.getContentPane()) 
     frame.dispose();
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Comment: Well I have to use applet for my thing, matter of personal preference also. 

I just need to know why I can switch contents of applet (like all the drawing etc) to jframe but not back to applet?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: frame = new JFrame();

frame.add(applet.getContentPane()); //applet == JApplet
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setResizable(false);
device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);

That code I use to turn the content from applet over the fullscreened jframe, now I want to dismiss fullscreen and return contents of jframe back to the applet, I get error saying I can't add parent something back to it.

if (device.getFullScreenWindow() != null) {
 device.getFullScreenWindow().dispose();
 device.setFullScreenWindow(null);

 applet.setContentPane(frame.getContentPane())
 frame.dispose();

Comment: That's not an SSCCE, and I cannot read code in comments.  [Edit the code into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18300705/edit).  Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.